# How to resolve following htaccess code

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

can any body explain me how above htaccess rule works
e.g. if I have URL http://mydomain/edituser
so what php script will match with given URL

earlier I write different rules for each given URL
but in above case how I know that witch php script get run
please help me

Comment: Thank you @Joe I am new here and I do not know how to format text while asking question. thank again.

Comment: @Abhijeet - that's fine, this is a very community oriented site. One day you will fix another person's question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That rewrite rule matches any request that does not match an existing file, and routes the request to to index.php using PATH_INFO

Answer (score 1):

Translation of the above code is like that:

`RewriteEngine On`: Activate the RewriteEngine if not already activated
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`: If the requested file name is not a regular file
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`: If the requested file name is not a regular directory
`RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)`: If the request is not the index.php, the images or robots.txt file
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]`: Send the request to index.php and stop ([L])

Answer (score 0):

This looks as a part from WordPress. If the file doesn't exists `(-f)` and a directory also not exists `(-d)` and the request is not for `index.php` or `images` or `robots.txt` when call `index.php` with the path as a parameter.